# How do I print a right triangle with alphabets?

Tags: c

```
A
A B
A B C
```

Please let me know how to print the above sequence.

Condition for spaces should be as below

```
A(no space)
A(space)B(no space)
A(space)B(space)C(no space)
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried and how it did not work. Look into loops if you haven't started working on this problem. Also, take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and other topics from [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: `printf("A\nA B\nA B C\n");`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is no "do my homework" site.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        int i = 65; //'A' = 65 ASCII value
        for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++) { 
            for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
            printf("%c", (char)i);
                i++;
                if (y < (x-1)) printf(" ");
            }
            printf("\n");
            i = 65;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Instead of 10 `x < 10`, insert how many lines with letters you want to be printed

Comment: there is a little mistake, so it does not print what op wants: https://ideone.com/13eUZv

Comment: the i must be in the loop of the for(int x = 1... else it won t restart to A https://ideone.com/67lyi4